# TkFiledialog.askopenfilename() launches a window for "save as" in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Using Tkinter to launch an open file dialog for use with other python functions results in a "save as" dialog opening.

Using this script:

```py
import tkFileDialog
file_path_string = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

I should get the open file dialog, and instead i get a "save file" dialog.

I'm using spyder IDE within the as-downloaded anaconda 3.7 windows installer

```py
import tkFileDialog
file_path_string = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

Answer (score 2):

the IDE is attempting to save the script file before executing (as should be expected).  This is the problem, not an issue with the script.